# How mark my question as answered on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

I tried looking around for a way to modify my questions so that they appear as solved... I wasn't able to find anything here on Stack Overflow.

So my question is, how do you do it? I just want to be able to mark my questions as solved in some way.

Comment: You didn't read the FAQ did you?  http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Yes I did read the FAQ (was kinda hard to find if you ask me), the problem is, it does say that it shows you have accepted an answer, but that doesn't necessarily mean that you solved your problem, know what I mean.

Comment: You shouldn't mark an answer as "the answer" if it didn't solve your problem.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You simply need to mark an answer as correct (the green check image).

Comment: The funny thing is, he has marked one of his two questions as answered.  This question being the one of the two he hasn't marked an answer for.

Comment: @Gromer Yeah, check my comment to LittleBobbyTales, like I said, I wasn't sure that that would actually set my question as answered, I thought it would just be something to show that that question has been approved by me as a helpful answer.

Comment: No worries man, I'm glad you got it figured out.  I'd rather have people ask how to mark an answer as the solution, as opposed to people never marking questions as solved!  Also, might as well delete this question as a lot of SO users will loose their mind when they see this and downvote this question all day long.

Answer (score 12):

Click the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer that solved your problem. This marks the answer as "accepted", and by extension the question as "has an accepted answer".

If you solved the question yourself without help from an answer, post an answer yourself describing the solution, and then accept that.